# Chords of a 20-gon

Tags: combinatorics, puzzle, pigeonhole-principle

Twenty points lie on a circle, so as to form a regular polygon. Then they are split into ten pairs, and the points in each pair are connected by a chord. Prove that some pair of these chords have the same length.

At first i thought this was be a simple case of pigeon hole principle. But it is not that, as there are 10 possible lengths and there are 10 chords.

Comment: Have you considered trying to first look at smaller cases, such as 6-gons and 8-gons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We label the distances $1,2,3\dots 10$ according to the congruence of $v_1-v_2\bmod10$. Suppose we have split it up. Then

$v_1-v_2+v_3-v_4+\dots v_{19}-v_{20}=v_1+v_2+v_3+\dots+v_{20}-2(v_2+v_4+v_6+\dots v_{20})\equiv 0\bmod 2$

However if we had distances $1,2,3\dots10$ the sum of the distances would be $55$ so it is impossible to do this.

Comment: In short. the sum of distances must be even, but if all are different it would be odd.

Comment: How are the vertices labelled? I think we need $\min(|v_1-v_2|,20-|v_1-v_2|)$ to label the distances.

Comment: but just by knowing the congrunce of $v_1-v_2\bmod 10$ we can know the distance.

Comment: we label them from smallest to largest.

Comment: can you elaborate on how the labeling is done?

Comment: Well, the longest chord is labeled 10 and the shortest is labeled $1$. However notice that the chord going from vertex $v_1$ to $v_2$ gets the label $k$ if and only if $v_1-v_2\equiv k \bmod 10$

Answer (score 0):

If we're talking about the chords of the 20-gon (dodecagon), then the chords between ajacent points don't count (they don't lie inside the polygon) as chords and there are only 9 possible lengths.

If the chords are on the circle then it's definitely more complicated as you suggest.

Comment: If it is chords of a circle, I would suggest a proof by contradiction.

Comment: chords between adjacent point are included here.

Comment: btw dodecagon is a 12-gon